# Java error in making file through console

Tags: java, runtime, mkdir

I want to make a file though the cmd in java using this code

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mkdir C:\\Users\\Nick\\test");
```

and i get this annoying error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mkdir": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
at LFID.main(LFID.java:11)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
... 5 more
```

I have no idea what's causing it so help.

By the way please don't tell me how to create a folder not through cmd, I need to do it this way. Thanks.

Comment: NIck, does that exist? and do you have the permissions?

Answer (score 6):

`mkdir` isn't a standalone executable you can launch as a separate process - it's a command that the Windows command shell understands.

So you *could* run `cmd.exe /c mkdir ...`:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c mkdir c:\\Users\\Nick\\test");
```

Or:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
    new String[] { "cmd.exe", "/c" "mkdir" "c:\\Users\\Nick\\test"});
```

... but I'd still recommend just using [`File.mkdir`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir--) instead... why call out to an external process when you can do it within Java? (If you're going to specify an odd requirement, it helps to give some more context on it...)